# "Expose" effect in a Mac application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, applescript

Is there any way or function that can be used to obtain the expose effect in Mac, when a button is clicked?

I tried searching, but I had no luck, so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API for this. AFAIK the only way to do it is to use `NSWorkspace` to launch either the **Exposé** app (Mac OS X versions < 10.7) or the **Mission Control** app (Mac OS X versions >= 10.7).

This code uses the `com.apple.exposelauncher` bundle ID which is the same for all versions of Mac OS X that ship with Exposé:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchAppWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.exposelauncher" 
                                                     options:NSWorkspaceLaunchDefault 
                              additionalEventParamDescriptor:NULL 
                                            launchIdentifier:NULL];
```

Comment: Adding to Rob's comment, this works in applescript... tell application id "com.apple.exposelauncher" to launch.

Comment: @Rob: Thanks for the reply it really helped but here's one more query that i had in my mind like could we have a script or some bundle identifier that would work like fn+f11 to show the desktop.